# testcasesource list of input data and expected result

Tags: nunit

I am trying the following:

```
private readonly object[] _integerListsAndExpectedResults = {new object[] {new List<decimal> {1}, 1},  
new object[] {new List<decimal> {1, 2}, 3} 
};

[Test, TestCaseSource("_integerListsAndExpectedResults")]
public void GivenListOfIntegers_WhenIAddThem_ThenTheResultsAreCorrect(List<decimal> testList, decimal expectedResult)
{
...
```

but unfortunately it does not work as expected. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have tried running your code and I found that Nunit runner is not able to map int with decimal.

you just need to change the type of your input by adding **M** in the end of input parameters. Please refer the below code-

```
private readonly object[] _integerListsAndExpectedResults = {
    new object[] {new List<decimal> {1M}, 1M},  
    new object[] {new List<decimal> {1M, 2M}, 3M} 
};

[Test, TestCaseSource("_integerListsAndExpectedResults")]
public void GivenListOfIntegers_WhenIAddThem_ThenTheResultsAreCorrect(
    List<decimal> testList, decimal expectedResult)
{
```

Comment: Thanks excellent. BTW, it seems to work without m if one does not use the second expected value. Could be a bug in nunit ...